# Shell script user switch

Tags: linux, shell, debian, sudo, su

I am running a simple shell script which creates a user and then switches to it so that I can run a bunch of commands as the new user. The script below is ran as the `root` on a Debian 9 (Stretch) amd64 host and is not showing what I would expect. This is just a test script for me to see what's going on.

```
#!/bin/sh
adduser karl --gecos "First Last, RoomNumber, WorkPhone, HomePhone" --disabled-password
adduser karl sudo
echo 'karl:password123' | chpasswd
echo 'karl ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/karl

echo
sudo su - karl
whoami # prints root?
echo

echo
sudo -u karl /usr/bin/whoami # prints karl
echo

exit 0
```

Comment: You might want to put all the "karl" commands in a separate file, then do `sudo su -c /path/to/karl_commands.sh - karl`

Comment: Also, if you're already root, you don't need `sudo su`, just use `su`

Comment: @glennjackman, Thanks